# How to load new Activity onclick <button>?

Tags: javascript, android, android-activity, webview

How to change Activity , load new Activity, when I click on  inside HTML page which I shows inside WebView. Demo.html is in assets. How to load new Activity ?
This is Demo.html inside assets

```
<html>
        <script language="javascript">
            /* This function is invoked by the activity */
                function wave() {
                    alert("1");
                        //What to do to change on new Activity
                        alert("2");
                }
        </script>
        <body>
            <!-- Calls into the javascript interface for the activity -->
            <a onClick="window.demo.clickOnAndroid()">
            <div style="width:80px;
                        margin:0px auto;
                        padding:10px;
                        text-align:center;
                        border:2px solid #202020;" >
                                <input id="test" type="button" onclick="wave">Click Me!</button>
                </div></a>

        </body>
</html>
```

What to do so when I click on button with id="test" I go to new activity in android app, like I do in normal way when use Button in android, not in JavaScript

```
 Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Test.class);
                        startActivity(i);
```

Comment: just clarify your question. what you want to do?

Comment: I think he actually wants to launch an Activity from a webview.

Comment: ok, can you call any dummy url on button click with id="test" like, when the button clicked on webview (button with id="test") then any dummy url call..

Answer (score 0):

If I have understand correct (meaning start a new Activity when clicking on the button) you should check here for a complete guide: http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html and more specifically the section 'Binding JavaScript code to Android code'. Try this and if you have any problem come back again. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this.[What WebView can do in Android ?](http://prasanta-paul.blogspot.com/2011/08/what-webview-can-do-in-android.html). This blog shows how to call an android activity or method via javascript.